# Make a link call a specific CSS stylesheet on the target document

Tags: html, css

Quick overview of what I have and what I'm looking to do:

- MASTER page has a drop-down with four links to respective log-in pages. Login --> 4 links (children, teenagers, adults, seniors)
- There is only 1 log-in page that holds 4 css stylesheets, depending on which type of person you are (children, teenagers, adults, seniors)
- I want the link on the master page to take the user immediately to the login page with the correct css stylesheet in place.
- I know how to get this to work on the log-in page itself, but not how to call the specific css stylesheets from a link on a different page.

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a url parameter and switch function...
In PHP you can use it:

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
switch($page){
case"children":
  $style_link = "<link href="CHILDREN LINK STYLESHEET" rel="stylesheet"/>";
break;
case"teenagers":
  $style_link = "<link href="TEENAGERS LINK STYLESHEET" rel="stylesheet"/>";
break;
case"adults":
  $style_link = "<link href="ADULTS LINK STYLESHEET" rel="stylesheet"/>";
break;
case"seniors":
  $style_link = "<link href="SENIORS LINK STYLESHEET" rel="stylesheet"/>";
break;
}
?>
```

and your print it in your html code:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <?php echo $style_link;?>
   </head>
........
</html>
```

then don't forget to add url parameter to every drop-down link like it:

`www.your-site.com/login.php?page=children
www.your-site.com/login.php?page=adults
...
etc`

Comment: Michael Antonius, Thank you very much.

This worked beautifully. Only thing that needed changing was the blockquotes ("") within the <link href...> which need to be single quotes (' ')

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but i'm happy i can help you !

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about ;) You did much more than I expected!